# JavaScript Loads Fine in PHP project but not in Python project?

Tags: javascript, python

This code loads without error in a PHP project:

```
function waitForElement() {
  const observablesTitles = $('.observables-title');
  if (typeof observablesTitles === 'undefined') {
    setTimeout(function(){ waitForElement(); }, 250);
  } else {
    let a = 100;
    a *= a;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    waitForElement();
});
```

...but when I load it in a Python project, via Chrome dev tools, I see the text after `$(document).ready` missing:

[image: javascript text cut off?]

What could explain this?

Comment: Please give more information about your Python project and you added the script.

Comment: I'm new to Python. It's an existing in-production Python app. It's using an old version of jQuery, 1.11. I'm coding a new javascript file and loading it via an html `<script>` tag. What other kinds of info can I provide that would be helpful?

Comment: Force-reloading the page fixed it once-- but after another edit, the anomaly recurs and force-reloading isn't taking care of it. When the content isn't being cut off, I'm getting a lot of `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` errors.

Comment: Everything works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome! I just disabled all Chrome extensions, quit and re-opened Chrome, and I'm still getting the same errors. What IS this?

Comment: I fixed it by moving the javascript file out of the build folder for the python project, and to an entirely different web server. I don't yet know why that fixed it. Perhaps a build error in the python project? A source maps error?